# I can't find: System.Transactions Namespace

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use transaction LINQ, but I cant' find the `TransactionScope Class`.

Help please. Thanks...

Answer (score 101, accepted):

usually `System.Transactions` is not part of your references, try to add it in your references by:

- right click on your references if you are using Web Application or in your Project if you are using Web Site.
- find the `System.Transactions` in the `.NET` references.

You should find the `System.Transactions` in your references.

Comment: Yeah, it's not obvious but you've got to click the little box in the left-hand column after you find System.Transactions in the list, then click OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!! I loose time checking where i was wrong and wondering about my EF (EF6).

Comment: In my case I also needed to include a using directive  `using System.Transactions;` after this step. Unsure in my case if checking this box in references was necessary, but I did it.

Comment: What if System.Transactions is not in that checklist? I can't find it even using the "Search" box.

Comment: How about for someone targeting netstandard2.0 or netstandard2.1, is there a package one can reference?

Answer (score 2):

If you guys working with console application than right click on the References inside of your project than Add references and a window will pop up,
inside of this window find the Assemblies, left click on Assemblies. There will be pop up a list of assemblies look for Transaction... good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2017+, right click on project **References**, select **Add reference**.

Select, in the left tree view of the opened window, **Assembly > Framework**: scroll the list and you will find `System.Transactions`.

Check it and press OK to add it to the project references.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And for those of us trying to add it to our `web.config`:

- `<add assembly="System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>`

As in:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <compilation>
         <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
         </assemblies>
      </compilation>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

- **Assembly**: `System.Transctions`
- **Version**: `4.0.0.0`
- **Culture**: `neutral`
- **PublicKeyToken**: `B77A5C561934E089` *(the low 8 bytes of the sha1 fingerprint of the public key)*

**Note**: the PublicKeyToken (fingerprint of the signing certificate) is different from nearly ever other assembly in the .NET framework.

- most assembly signing certificate "public key token": `B03F5F7F11D50A3A`
- the `System.Transactions` assembly public key token: `B77A5C561934E089`